# Makefile string comparison #ifeq

Tags: makefile

In one of my projects, I am facing the error below. I have two environments and I'm observing the `ifeq` functionality difference between the two environments.

In the first environment, the below code is working fine.

```
FIRST = 1

ifeq ( ($FIRST),1 ) 

 ENABLE_CODE+= -D'ENABLE_PROGRAM'

endif
```

The same code is not working in the second environment. It only works if I modify the code

```
 ifeq ( ($FIRST),1)
```

to

```
 ifeq ( ( $FIRST),'1')
```

Could somebody help me to sort this out?

Comment: shoulden't it be $(FIRST)?

Comment: Which version(s) of Make are you using?

Answer (score 3):

As told in the comment you should wrap `FIRST` into quotes: `$(FIRST). Note, the Makefile and Bash has different syntax. Makefile require round quotes around variable, bash - not.

Also please remove extra whitespaces inside `ifeq`. Note in some cases command `ifeq ( $(FIRST),1 )` may compare with unstriped line and fail because of extra whitespaces: it may compare to `'1 '` instead of simple `'1'`

So makefile will looks like

```
FIRST = 1

ifeq ($(FIRST),1)
   ENABLE_CODE += -D'ENABLE_PROGRAM'
endif

all:
        @echo FIRST $(FIRST)
        @echo ENABLE_CODE $(ENABLE_CODE)
```